# Can anyone tell me the library name for PhotoViewImage Entityframework class in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i can't find any library for "Photo view image" entity framework class....I have tried to find it out in Google, but didn't get a proper answer. I will post my controller code here.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Upload(PhotoForSingleItem file)
{
PhotoViewImage newImage = new PhotoViewImage();
HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["OriginalLocation"];
newImage.ContentType = file.ContentType;
Int32 length = file.ContentLength;
byte[] tempImage = new byte[length];
file.InputStream.Read(tempImage, 0, length);
newImage.ActualImage = tempImage ;
return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a built-in (EntityFramework) class. It appears to be a custom class created by someone else.

Comment: here is the link for the tutorial: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/689_Uploading_and_Displaying_Files_Using_ASP_NET_MVC_Framework.aspx